# How to get a command line parameter?

Tags: linux

suppose I am passing a command line parameters to my shell script as follows :

ex 1 ) ./myshell_script a b c d e f

ex 2 ) ./myshellscript f d e b c a

My question is that , If I want to get the parameter "c" that is always after parameter  "b"  [ since the command line parameters may be provided in any order ] , How I can get the value that is always after parameter "b" ?

Comment: As you know, parameters are numbered `$1`, `$2`, and so on.  So you should find position of the b and use next parameter.  Also, you could parse list of parameters `$*`.  Read `man sh` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ./a.sh f d e b c a
c
```

code

```
#!/bin/bash

i=
for p in $@; do

    if [ "$i" == "1" ];then
        echo $p
        exit
    fi
    if [ "$p" == "b" ];then
        i=1
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `getopts`

It's good practice not to rely on parameters orders, but instead assign them to unambiguous values using `getopts`. This allow you to write things as `./myshell_script -a a -b b -c c -d d -d e -f f` which is equivalent to any permutation of it `./myshellscript -f f -d d -e e -b b -c c -a a`.

Not having to worry about order is well worth the couple of extra lines at the beginning of the script and extra characters in its call.

[Getopts Tutorial on Bask-hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial#using_it)

Answer (score 0):

**myshellscript**

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -oP 'b\s*\K[^ ]+' <<<$*
```

Test:

```
% myshellscript a b c d e f
c
% myshellscript f d e b c a
c
```

Comment: @user2930942 Welcome! It seems you're new to this site. If any ans is working for you, consider accepting that ans by clicking on hollow green tick mark besides ans. P.S. I noticed you haven't accepted ans for any of your 4 questions